# graphviz dot to pdf: distance from graph to title

Tags: dot

in graphviz dot, generating pdf output.

how do I increase the distance between the title and the graph?

```
digraph "test" {
   graph [ label="need more distance to below"  ];
   A -> B;
}
```

advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not preferable solution but Append "\n" at the end of label. If you need more space add more "\n".